# Liquibase default schema not being used

Tags: liquibase

I am running `liquibase` in a database for the first time with the following parameters specified in a property file.

**property file**

```
username: abc
driver: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
defaultSchemaName: abcrpt
```

The `databaseChangeLog` file contains a simple `changeSet` that creates a test table. The `DATABASECHANGELOG` and `DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK` tables are created as `abcrpt` but the test table is created as `abc`. What am I doing wrong?   Thanks!

**databaseChangeLog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 

<databaseChangeLog
   xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
   http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd"> 

   <preConditions>
      <dbms type="DB2"/>
   </preConditions>

   <include file="db2\viewname_changeSet_005.xml"/>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

**viewname_changeSet_005.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 

<databaseChangeLog
   xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
   http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd"> 

   <changeSet id="Drop Table STPL_TEST" author="JoanB">
      <preConditions onFail="CONTINUE">
         <sqlCheck expectedResult="1">SELECT COUNT(*) FROM syscat.tables where tabname = 'STPL_TEST'</sqlCheck>
       </preConditions>
      <sql>
         DROP TABLE STPL_TEST; 
      </sql>
   </changeSet>

   <changeSet id="Create Table STPL_TEST" author="JoanB">
      <sql>
         CREATE TABLE STPL_TEST (
           ST_ID     BIGINT NOT NULL,
           ST_VCHAR  VARCHAR(10),
           ST_DATE   DATE
         );
      </sql>
   </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because your table is created with raw SQL. Liquibase does not have any sort of SQL parser and so just executes SQL directly.

If you use more semantic tags like `<createTable>` instead, then Liquibase will know how to add the default schema attribute to the generated SQL.

Comment: Is there a predefined property (that contains the current schema) one could use in a sql statement? For example: `<sql>create table ${LB.SCHEMA}.some_table ...</sql>`

Comment: You could try ${database.defaultCatalogName}  or ${database.defaultSchemaName}. I believe DB2 doesn't support two levels of object containers so liquibase calls DB2 schemas catalogs and ${database.defaultCatalogName}  is your better bet.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you can use:

```
       <sql>
         CREATE TABLE ${database.defaultSchemaName}.STPL_TEST (
           ST_ID     BIGINT NOT NULL,
           ST_VCHAR  VARCHAR(10),
           ST_DATE   DATE
         );
      </sql>
```

Hope this helps the next person